# Open links in browser for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, facebook, browser

I have an app, where the user can upload an image, crop it, add frame to it and then download the result image. It works perfectly if you open it in browser, on the desktop and the mobile devices. But, there is one problem. For example, if I post this page's link on Facebook, it opens it's own safe browsing google tab where downloading an image is blocked and I could't find a way to force the app to open link only in the browser. I didn't included my code because code is not a problem. I need a way to open link from Facebook in the browser. Thanks in advance!